# D3 Force Directed Graph Design

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, force-layout

Can someone review my implementation on JSFiddle and give me some pointers making my code cleaner and robust?

I've been working on this in JsFiddle. I am attempting to get a nice clean graph implementation for workflow design. For instance, we have input and output nodes and processes in between. Although I've done linq style functional programming in C#, this javascript implementation is a bit tougher to get my head around. All of the functionality that I want is in the various example pieces of code. I have attempted to bring them together, but it could be tidier and nicer.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ckG5/9/

[image]

These definitions confuse me, they have different names and properties across the examples. Really not getting it.

```
var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);
```

The object scopes confuse me and I don't fully understand them.

Here is a list of functionality, a bold text indicates working. This example forms the basis of the implementation (http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347), and others are linked next to the bit of functionality that they confer. However i am getting confused as they each work slightly differently and bringing them together is more of a challenge than anticipated.

**Nodes**

**Nodes repel each other with charge value**

**Control node colour**

**Control node radius**

**Control node label**

**Delete a node**

Deleting a node, also deletes that node's inputs and outputs       //Node selector???

Node dragging and repositioning. kinda.... but oh so buggy   (http://bl.ocks.org/norrs/2883411)

Only process nodes can be dragged and repositioned.

Node inputs or outputs repositioned based on associated process node position.

**Labels on nodes**

**Only node inputs and outputs can form links**

**Only node inputs can connect to node outputs and vice versa.**

**Can only connect if same input/output type**

Change colour of all nodes of the same type that can be connected to, when going to connect two nodes.

**Links**

**Set link lengths**

**A drag line is is made on mouse down.**

**Markers on links**

Markers always point from input to output.

**Area**

Pan/Zoom (http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043)

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

DUPLICATED IN STACKEXCHANGE..... although they feel it is off topic on there. Anyone? Anyone at all have some positive input here?

Comment: This may be better asked on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Well hopefully, sadly they do not have a d3js tag for posting. I do not have enough reputation to create this tag or use more than one link in my post. I feel if anyone is able to offer assistance, they will want to follow the links to relevant code. That said, i've posted and fingers crossed i can find someone who can help me.